# In competing consumer pattern,can we have the conusmer produce the results in sequential fashion?

Tags: c#

Scenario:-

1. Producer produces a object with unique id associated with it and adds to the blocking collection queue.
2. I have 5 competing consumers which consumes the above data in a async fashion.
3. These 5 consumers pushes the processed data to a queue which is then used for logging.

Problem:

1. The logging is not happening in a seqeuntial fashion since the competing consumers push the processed data in a random fashion.

Question:-

1. Can we have the competing consumer push the data in a sequential fashion so that order is maintained?

Comment: I mean, it's possible, but would result in each of your 5 consumers to have to synchronise and as such potentially wait until the work started earlier is actually done, this could lead to all of your consumers being stuck waiting until one finishes. IMO it'd be easier for whatever is logging the output to keep track of the results in a list and then log it sequentially. So "only" the actual logging of stuff waits for earlier work to finish before continuing to work

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks for your suggestion but the frequency of the data that is generated is quite high its like 30 data objects per second,if we try to wait while logging there is a chance that the logging will have a different time stamp than that of the actual recieved time.

Comment: You can either block the consumers doing the work, or block the logger writing the log if you want sequential logs like that. I'd go with blocking the logger, and adding something like `[Info 12:00:057] Work object with id '1' started at '12:00:47' finished executing at '12:00:50'` so you know when it was logged, what ID the work object has, when it was started, and when it was finished, I highly suggest you **don't** rely on the log timestamp to actually identify when a piece of work finished executing (as logging, especially buffered logging, can be slow)